# Gradle: Execution failed for task androidlib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle

I faced with tricky error, have no clue the reason.

```
Execution failed for task ':unityLibrary:MyModule.androidlib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> com/google/auto/common/BasicAnnotationProcessor
```

Full description:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/auto/common/BasicAnnotationProcessor
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.AnnotationProcessingCompileTask.loadProcessor(AnnotationProcessingCompileTask.java:129)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.AnnotationProcessingCompileTask.setupProcessors(AnnotationProcessingCompileTask.java:108)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.AnnotationProcessingCompileTask.call(AnnotationProcessingCompileTask.java:92)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ResourceCleaningCompilationTask.call(ResourceCleaningCompilationTask.java:57)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:55)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:40)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:97)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:51)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:37)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.execute(AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.java:51)
```

My configuration:

```
  dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
    }

distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
```

Android Studio

```
Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1
Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7583922
Runtime version: 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 11.5
```

Java

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_282"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_282-bre_2021_01_20_16_06-b00)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.282-b00, mixed mode)
```

**Clean,  rebuild, clean Gradle cache do not help to solve the problem**